# Comparação com 3 tabelas

Tags: mysql

```
create table Pessoa (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar(150) not null,
    cidade varchar(100) not null,
    cpf char(14) not null unique,
    rg int not null unique,
    INDEX idx_nome(nome)
);

create table conta(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    numero int not null,
    agencia int not null,
    saldo decimal(20,2) not null,
    pessoa_id int not null,
    foreign key(pessoa_id) references Pessoa(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    INDEX idx_numero_agencia(numero, agencia)
);

create table medico(
    pessoa_id  int primary key not null,
    especialidade varchar(100)not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(pessoa_id) references Pessoa(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

create table paciente (
    pessoa_id int primary key not null,
    doenca varchar(100)  not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(pessoa_id) references Pessoa(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

create table consulta(
    medico_id int,
    paciente_id int,
    horario datetime not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(medico_id) references medico(pessoa_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY(paciente_id) references paciente(pessoa_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    INDEX idx_medico_horario(medico_id,horario),
    INDEX idx_paciente_horario(paciente_id,horario)
);
```

---

```
select Pessoa.nome `Nome do Médico`,
    Pessoa.cpf `CPF do Médico`,
    Pessoa.nome `Nome do Paciente`,
    Pessoa.cpf `CPF do Paciente`,
    consulta.horario `Horário da Consulta`
    from Pessoa inner join consulta on (consulta.medico_id = Pessoa.id) 
    inner join medico on (consulta.medico_id = Pessoa.id)
    inner join paciente on (consulta.paciente_id= Pessoa.id)
    order by consulta.horario asc;
```

Eu criei um banco onde uma pessoa pode ser um medico ou paciente, mas quando vou mostrar a tabela que mostra o  nome e o cpf do medico, e o nome e o cpf do paciente, dá erro.

Comment: Qual o erro? Criei as tabelas e executei a query e funcionou. A única diferença foi em usar ' ' e não ` ´

Comment: Use left no lugar do inner join.

Comment: Sua consulta não tem nenhum erro de sintaxe aparentemente. Poderia postar o erro que está ocorrendo?

Comment: O objetivo é mostrar as seguintes colunas: Nome do Médico, CPF do Médico, Nome do Paciente, CPF do Paciente e Horário da Consulta. Mas toda vez que eu executo, a tabela fica em branco